# Почему <T super String> в объявлении класса не работает?

Tags: java, generics, syntax, wildcards

```
class Solution <T super String> {
} 
//Ошибка: "Синтаксическая ошибка в лексеме "super"; ожидается ,"
```

Что мешает компилятору при попытке создать объект этого класса, проверять, является ли указанный аргумент для дженерика типом String или его любым из суперклассов?

Comment: может потому что extends вместо super надо использовать?

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411256/why-super-keyword-in-generics-is-not-allowed-at-class-level

Comment: @Dred, вопрос именно про super (extends означает, что подойдёт только любой из подклассов, а нужно, что бы пропускал только любой из суперклассов).

Comment: Потому что это не имеет смысла? Среди родителей String есть Object, который покрывает вообще любой класс.

Comment: @vp_arth, Всмысле покрывает? Если при объявлении класса <T super String> значит, что создавая объект, мы не сможет написать аргумент дженерика <Integer> (потому что не является супер от String), то уже маска не "покрыла любой класс" (а ограничила список аргументов, как и задумывалось). Вот например, рабочая маска с super в другом месте: `Class1<? super String> s = new Solution<Integer>();` (ошибка не соответствия типов - не покрыла всё), а так типы совместимы: `Class1<? super String> s = new Solution<String>();` – всё работает, а при объявлении класса нет смысла?

Comment: А что мешает ошибку включить в текст вопроса? Почему я должен это сам компилировать?

Comment: @defaultlocale, я думал, что для такого вопроса, не требуется смотреть текст ошибки, что бы ответить; но я учту на будущее.